# Error: Could not find or load main class Hangman.java

Tags: java

Hi Guys Getting this error "Error: Could not find or load main class Hangman.java" when i try to run the file.It compiles fine.Could you please advise what is missing. This a hangman game with the following attributes
**-the secret word

-the disguised word, in which each unknown letter in the secret word is replaced wit a question mark (?).
 For example, if the secret word is "abracadabra" and the letters a,b, and e have been guessed, the disguised word would be ab?a?a?ab?a.**
**-the number of guess made
-the number of incorrect guesses**

**It will have the following methods:

-makeGuess (c) guesses that character c is in the word

-getDisguisedWord returns a string containing correctly guessed letters in their correct positions and unknown letters replaced with "?"

-getSecretWord returns the secret word

-getGuessCount returns the number of guesses made

-isFound returns true if the hidden word has been discovered**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hangman {
   private String secretWord;
   private String disguisedWord ="";
   private String guessedLetters = "";
   private int numberOfGuesses = 0;
   private int numberOfIncorrectGuesses = 0;

   Hangman(String secretWord){
     this.secretWord = secretWord;
     for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++){
       this.disguisedWord += "?";
     }
   }

   public String getSecretWord() {
        return secretWord;
   }

   public String getGuesses() {
        return guessedLetters;
   }

   public String getDisguisedWord() {
        return disguisedWord;
   }

   public int getGuessCount() {
        return numberOfGuesses;
   }

   public int getIncorrectGuessCount() {
        return numberOfIncorrectGuesses;
   }

   public boolean isFound() {
        if (secretWord.equalsIgnoreCase(disguisedWord)){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
   }

   public boolean makeGuess(char guess) {

        for (int i = 0; i < guessedLetters.length(); i++){
            if (guess == guessedLetters.charAt(i)) {
                System.out.println("You have already guessed that letter.");
                return false;
             }
        }

        guessedLetters+= guess;
        String tempString = "";
        numberOfGuesses++;
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
                if (guess == secretWord.charAt(i)){
                    tempString += guess;
                } else {
                    tempString += disguisedWord.charAt(i);
                }
        }
        if (!tempString.equalsIgnoreCase(disguisedWord)) {
                disguisedWord = tempString;
                return true;
        } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Guess!");
                numberOfIncorrectGuesses++;
                return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        Hangman hangman = new Hangman("pirate"); // enter secret word as a string

        while (hangman.isFound()== false){
            System.out.println("The word is: " + hangman.getDisguisedWord());
            System.out.println("Guess a letter or type 'guesses' to see your guesses.");
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("guesses"))
                {
                    System.out.println(hangman.getGuesses());
                }
                else
                {
                    hangman.makeGuess(input.charAt(0));
                }
            }

            System.out.println("The secret word was: " + hangman.getSecretWord());
            System.out.println("It took you " + hangman.getGuessCount() + " guesses to get the correct answer.");
            System.out.println("You had " + hangman.getIncorrectGuessCount()+ " incorrect guesses.");
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: Is the class contained in a package? Java may not load classes in the default package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the program using :

`java -cp . Hangman`

and not

`java Hangman.java`

The important thing to understand here is that

1. You compile java classes using `javac <classname>.java`
2. You run java programs using `java <classname>` (Notice that there is no .java  required while running the program)

Comment: Isn't `-cp .` the default?

Comment: @immibis Not really. The `java` command does not look for other `.class `files in the current directory by default.

Comment: Your code compiles and runs fine. tested from eclipse and cmdline without the -cp. Are you running the class file, or are you trying to run the .java source?

Comment: @JohannisK The -cp is optional so that dependant class are found. The actual issue as that the OP is running the program as `java Hangman.java`. The `.java` is not required as pointed out in my answer if you take a closer look.

Comment: @bot I gave you an up for the answer, but I think your missing that he might not be running the compiled version of his source. If he's using an IDE it's possible the compiled version is in a different folder. 
Running java Hangman in the folder with the Hangman.java will still result in the same problem. That's why I asked the question about the compiled version. There should be a Hangman.class in the folder where he runs java Hangman

Comment: @JohannisK Agreed. But the OP said it compiles fine. By this I assume that he can see the .class file where it is supposed to be.

Comment: @bot Your answer, especially after the edit is correct, but your example is misleading. You suggest that running java Hangman.java is incorrect, where java -cp . Hangman is. This is only true if a Hangman.class is there. Your example would have been better if it was java Hangman.class is wrong, java Hangman is correct.

Comment: @JohannisK `Could not find or load main class Hangman.java`. The error message is pretty clear.